# What does it mean part of this code "seperature | | i"?

Tags: c++

I am new for "C++" so I don't understand the following part of code. 
The "data" is the String just like "Hello World" and seperature equals to this char "|". So what does it mean this line `"data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex"`

```
int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
    if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
      found++;
      strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
      strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `||` is simply a "logical OR". So if the first condition is true (character at position `i` is the special separator character), **or** the second condition is true (we hit the end), enter the code block below. Interestingly, if the first condition proves to be true, the second condition is irrelevant, so it doesn't even get checked (this is known as *short-circuiting*).

Comment: data="Hello"  so maxIndex=4 and for example i =0 So data.CharAt(0)=H and this is always false am i right ?data.charAt(i) return char and maxIndex return integer how can i compare with char and integer so e this it does not make sense thats why i dont understand

Comment: @BoBTFish why not puting it as an answer instead of a comment ?

Comment: @txemsukr Because I don't really have time to flesh out the detail with a worked example. I'd rather put a comment than a bad answer. (Sadly not everyone follows this).

Comment: @CKocar To be honest, I'm not really clear on what this code is trying to do. Could you please post a full [mcve]?

Comment: @BoBTFish bad answers have the advantage of being up/downvotable while too often bad comments get upvotes and more attention than they should

Comment: Thank you for your answer i examine the following codes:  https://github.com/nkolban/ESP32_BLE_Arduino/pull/16/commits/2e1f12eead46a2f34e2482fef2897d7ce1cd51cf  (my question is in the getValue method)

Comment: @CKocar I think I see your confusion now. You think the OR applies to `separator || i`, which yes, would be pretty confusing. It actually applies to the *entire* first condition `(data.charAt(i) == separator)` **or** the second condition `(i == maxIndex)`.

Comment: Yes, i understand now. That was very simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex
```

is an [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) that is [contextually convertible to bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). That expression is part of the [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) condition. The `||` operator is a [logical operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) `OR`. Simply speaking you have:

```
if (A OR B)
```

Where `A` in your case is `data.charAt(i) == separator` and `B` is `i == maxIndex`. We can think of `A` and `B` as operands.

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the compiler knows what `A` and `B` are and how to *cut* the entire expression into smaller expressions that make up operands. Both expressions have the [equality operator ==](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) in them. So thinking about `separator || i` as being an expression is wrong.

The logical operator `||` groups [left to right](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.log.or) which means `A` gets evaluated first and `B` might not get evaluated if `A` is `true`.

Comment: maybe add something about operator precedence